# Какая программа используется для чертежей (есть только скрины)

Tags: графика

Какая программа используется для чертежей [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не относится к программированию или системному администрированию

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD

AutoCAD — двух- и трёхмерная система автоматизированного проектирования и черчения, разработанная компанией Autodesk. Первая версия системы была выпущена в 1982 году. AutoCAD и специализированные приложения на его основе нашли широкое применение в машиностроении, строительстве, архитектуре и других отраслях промышленности. Программа выпускается на 18 языках. Уровень локализации варьирует от полной адаптации до перевода только справочной документации. Русскоязычная версия локализована полностью, включая интерфейс командной строки и всю документацию, кроме руководства по программированию.